# How to trigger (matSortChange)="sortData(i, $event)" for unit testing in angular app

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I am running unit test for an angular app. I want to manually trigger a matSortChange event and ensure a method is called upon firing this event

```
<table matSort (matSortChange)="sortData(i, $event)" matSortActive="enddate" matSortDirection="asc" matSortDisableClear style="margin:0px;" class="table table-striped table-bordered">

<tr>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let subheader of subheaders; let j = index">
  <ng-container *ngIf="subheader[1] == 'activationid'; else second">
    <th class="headers" style="width:300px;" mat-sort-header=" 
     {{subheader[1]}}">{{subheader[0]}} </th>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't try it in  unit test's but the `matSortChange` is triggered when the arrow for sorting is clicked. you could access the arrow from the `DOM` like

```
document.getElementsByClassName('mat-sort-header-arrow')[indexOfTheColumn].click()
```

This should fire the `matSortChange` event and don't forget to spy on `sortData` method to check the result.

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName('mat-sort-header-arrow')[0]; is returning me undefined

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName('mat-sort-header-arrow')  returns HTML objects

Comment: hmm,  the HTML objects are arrow elements?

Comment: test=document.getElementsByClassName('mat-sort-header-arrow');
 console.log(test.length);//prints 0

Comment: it is returning an empty array

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps to answer my question, this is the angular generated code, I saw this in the inspect element

```
 <div class="mat-sort-header-container">
  <button class="mat-sort-header-button" type="button" aria-label="Change sorting for 
   count"> Count </button>

  <div class="mat-sort-header-arrow ng-trigger ng-trigger-arrowPosition" 
   style="transform: translateY(25%); opacity: 0;">
    <div class="mat-sort-header-stem"></div><div class="mat-sort-header-indicator ng- 
     trigger ng-trigger-indicator" style="transform: translateY(0px);">
       <div class="mat-sort-header-pointer-left ng-trigger ng-trigger-leftPointer" 
        style="transform: rotate(-45deg);"></div>
       <div class="mat-sort-header-pointer-right ng-trigger ng-trigger-rightPointer" 
        style="transform: rotate(45deg);"></div>
       <div class="mat-sort-header-pointer-middle"></div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```